# Fasting on Chanukah

Tags: chanuka, fast-days

Are you allowed to fast on Chanukah?

Answer (score 6):

No. From the Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 670:1:

> ב כ״ה בכסליו מתחילין ח׳ ימי חנוכה ואסורים בהספד ותענית

Translated:

> The eight days of Chanukah begin on the 25th of Kislev, and eulogies and fasts are prohibited on these days.

However, the [Aruch Hashulchan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aruch_HaShulchan) states in Orach Chaim 670:6 that a fast because of a bad dream (a "Taanis Chalom" / "תענית חלום") would be permitted:

> ובחנוכה אסור להתענות לבד תענית חלום דמתענין
>   אפילו בשבת ויום טוב וצריך למיתב תענית לתעניתו כבשבת ויום טוב

Translated:

> On Chanukah it is forbidden to fast, except for a *Taanis Chalom* (which may be observed even on Shabbos and Yom Tov). One must then observe an additional fast day in compensation for fasting [on Chanukah], just as is required for Shabbos and Yom Tov.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's the only "Megillat Ta'anit" holiday that was not rescinded.